# Reference GeneratorFunction instance from within the function definition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to set properties on the instantiated GeneratorFunction. I want to be able to set the `length` property as a convenience, so the consumer can get an idea of how many values will be generated. For example:

```
function* produceValues(someInput) {
    this.length = determineLength(someInput)
    yield // something
}

const gen = produceValues(input)
console.log(gen.length)
```

Unsurprisingly, using `this` does not refer to the instance, but instead the global. Does JavaScript provide some way to access the instantiated object?

Comment: I've just filed https://github.com/allenwb/ESideas/issues/9. However, there's a larger issue: the code in the generator function doesn't start running until `next()` is called for the first time, so by then it would be too late to initialise `.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not, as `this` works for generator function to be used as methods, not to be used as constructors (which they are). So all you can do is

```
function* _produceValues(someInput) {
    yield // something
}
function produceValues(someInput) {
    var res = _produceValues(someInput);
    res.input = someInput;
    // or res.length = …
    return res;
}
produceValues.prototype = Object.defineProperties(_produceValues.prototype, {
    length: {
        get() { return determineLength(this.input); }
    }
});

const gen = produceValues(input);
console.log(gen instanceof produceValues);
console.log(gen.input);
console.log(gen.length);
```

---

We can also give this some crazy syntactical sugar:

```
function generatorClass(genFun) {
    function constructor(...args) { return Object.setPrototypeOf(genFun(...args), new.target.prototype); }
    constructor.prototype = genFun.prototype;
    return constructor;
}
class produceValues extends generatorClass(function*(someInput) {
    yield // something
}) {
    constructor(someInput) {
        super(someInput);
        this.input = someInput;
    }
    get length() {
        return determineLength(this.input);
    }
}
```

but then you'll have to use `const gen = new produceValues(input)`. It'll become clear though that `gen` is a special generator instance with extra properties.

Answer (score 1):

> Does JavaScript provide some way to access the instantiated object?

Not as far as I can tell – will read the spec more thoroughly – but there’s always:

```
function* produceValues_(someInput) {
    yield determineLength(someInput);
}

function produceValues(someInput) {
    const gen = produceValues_(someInput);
    gen.length = gen.next();
    return gen;
}
```